# Using Pandas Getdummies or isin to create Bool Features from feature that contains lists

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with one column containing a list of unique strings for each instance:

```
obj_movies['unique_genres'].head()

0    [Action, Fantasy, Adventure, Science Fiction]
1                     [Action, Fantasy, Adventure]
2                       [Action, Adventure, Crime]
3                 [Action, Drama, Thriller, Crime]
4             [Action, Science Fiction, Adventure]
Name: unique_genres, dtype: object
```

I would like to use pandas get_dummies() to create boolean features (to add on to the same dataframe) based on values in the list. For example, feature 'Action_Movie' would be True (or have value 1) for all first five instances.

To complete this task, I created a set of unique values from all the lists contained in the feature. With a for loop, for each movie tag feature (i.e. unique value in the set) I then used a boolean conversion method I created separately to create a list of 1's or a 0's based on the method outcomes. Finally, I simply appended as new pandas series.

However, I am thinking there must be a faster way! What about pandas df.isin() method for example? I also looked into that but it doesn't seem to work when you pass it a series of lists

What would be the best way to go about doing this? Can anyone recommend a good pandas advanced data manipulation tutorial online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so if your column is composed of lists, you can indeed use `get_dummies` on your column with a bit of transformation (`apply(pd.Series)`, `stack` and then `groupby`):

```
df_dummies = pd.get_dummies(obj_movies['unique_genres']
                                  .apply(pd.Series).stack()).groupby(level=0).sum()
```

then do add the column to your previous dataframe, use join:

```
obj_movies = obj_movies.join(df_dummies)
```

you should get your expected output

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! Would you recommend a specific advanced pandas tutorial??

Comment: @Odisseo unfortunately, I don't know a special good one, I started to learn with the [official one](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html) but I don't know if it is better than any other, and for advanced, it was more on SOF where I found answers to almost all question I had :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe, you need:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'movie':['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'genre':[['Action', 'Fantasy', 'Adventure', 'Science Fiction'],['Action', 'Fantasy', 'Adventure'],['Action', 'Adventure', 'Crime']]
})
dum = pd.get_dummies(df['genre'].apply(pd.Series).stack()).reset_index(1, drop=True)
dum.groupby(dum.index).sum()
```

Output:

```
   Action  Adventure  Crime  Fantasy  Science Fiction
0       1          1      0        1                1
1       1          1      0        1                0
2       1          1      1        0                0
```

And then, you can easily substitute these dummies back to the original dataframe using:

```
df.merge(dum.groupby(dum.index).sum(), left_index=True, right_index=True).drop('genre', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  movie  Action  Adventure  Crime  Fantasy  Science Fiction
0     a       1          1      0        1                1
1     b       1          1      0        1                0
2     c       1          1      1        0                0
```